# Can I install FIFA 11 in 2 PCs and access online features from both PC?

Tags: pc, fifa-11

I've never used online feature of any game. For the first time I'm gonna use FIFA 11's online features. I've a laptop and a desktop PC. Both having different IP addresses. I'd like to install FIFA 11 on both the laptop and desktop. Can I access FIFA 11's online features from both of them with same user id?

I'm wondering if EA Sports have some mapping of user id to ip address or something like that which will restrict me to access online features from only first installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might not be a mapping of IP address to user id - after all you might have a dynamic IP on your router - but there will be code that prevents the same user logging in twice at the same time.

They may allow multiple installations but only one being online at any time - check the documentation as this should be covered. Often only a single installation is allowed, but with on-line activation this isn't essential to restricting use to a single account at any one time.

To answer the specific question - it's extremely unlikely that you'll be able to install the game on two PCs and play the game from both of them *at the same time*.

Comment: Then I would be able to install as many copies as I want. Is that also correct?

Comment: @Donotalo - Possibly, but you'd have to check the license agreement.